# How can I get an interior element to scroll while allowing mobile browsers to hide the address bar?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs, outer is height: 100% and inner has a very long content and the content is dynamic.

If I set the inner div's height to 100vh, scroll works but in mobile browsers, the address bar is not going away.

If I set the inner div's height to 100%, scroll doesn't work on desktop but in a mobile browser, the address bar is going away and everything is fine.

I created a sample here:

```html
<div style="height: 100%; width: 300px; background-color: red; padding: 20px;">
  <div style="height: 100%;overflow: scroll;">
    <div style="height: 2900px; background-color:blue;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h152gn4w/

What is the best way to make scrollable safely both in mobile browsers and desktop?